# How to export an 'update package' from TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, export, project, package

I've made a handful changes to files within project folder, managed by TortoiseSVN (GUI, I'm not used to command line yet), but before commiting the changes, I'd like to export all the files that -have been changed- to a separate folder in order to update live installation with new files as well.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: There is an easy way to do this _after_ a commit, I've never tried to do this beforehand though.

Comment: How to do it after a commit? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the correct place to answer this, but here it is:

1. Right Click on your Repo
2. TortoiseSVN > Show Log
3. Highlight the two revisions you are comparing (Shift Click)
4. Right Click > Compare Revisions
5. Select all the files > Right Click > **Export selection to...**

Comment: This only gives me the list of files. I want to export all the files that have been changed in order to create an update package and upload it to FTP.

Comment: @kristovaher: This should give you a list of all the files that have been changed between the two revisions you selected.

Comment: @kristovaher: See my update, I'd made a reference to the wrong command on the file step - sorry.